# Bash script not working as required with xbindkeys

Tags: 12.04, bash, shortcut-keys, capslock

I made a simple bash script to display a notification whenever my capslock key is pressed. It works fine when I  call it like `bash capsnotify.sh`.

The problem now is when I bind my above script to `capslock` key using `xbindkeys` tool it doesn't work as required. It shows a notification `caps ON` when my caps is on but it doesn't show `caps OFF` notification when my caps is off instead it again shows the `caps ON` notification.

**capsnotify.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

value=$(xset -q | awk '/Caps/ {print $4}')

if [ "$value" == "on" ]

then    
    notify-send "caps ON"

elif [ "$value" == "off" ]

then    
    notify-send "caps OFF"    
fi
```

**.xbindkeysrc**

```
"bash /home/ranveer/capsnotify.sh"
  m:0x2 + c:66
```

So, the problem is after binding my caps lock key on both events(on/off) it shows `caps ON` notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me is adding `sleep` before the call to my script in `xbindkeys`. So, now my `.xbindkeysrc` looks like

```
"sleep 0.1 && bash /home/ranveer/capsnotify.sh"
```

I believe it works by adding `sleep` because the call to xset to query the state of CapsLock happens before the Xserver has toggled the state which might be due to my window manager which grabs the key event and doesn't process it super-quickly and thus X toggles a bit later.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to specify to `xbindkeys` that your script should be launched with `gnome-terminal` (or equivalent), for example, and minimise the size of the terminal. You could replace your entry in `~/.xbindkeysrc` with:

```
"gnome-terminal --geometry=1x1+1141+27 --hide-menubar -e /home/ranveer/capsnotify.sh"
 m:0x2 + c:66
```

We gained the geometry readout of the terminal by placing it at the top right hand corner of the screen and then running `xwininfo` and clicking on the window. By specifying such a small terminal (1x1) and its top right hand position (1141+27) and hiding the menubar, we can ensure that a thumbnail sized terminal actually opens momentarily underneath the caps lock notify messages at the top right of the screen. It should be possible to specify the geometry like this with other terminals such as well.

After any changes to `~/.xbindkeysrc`, you must enter

```
killall xbindkeys
```

and then

```
xbindkeys
```

for the new changes to be read.

In the screenshot below, I pressed caps-lock twice very quickly so that the first notify-send message had not yet disappeared:

[image]

There may be other ways of solving the problem, but this is a quick reliable one that does not entail any rewriting of your script or installing other programs.

Comment: `killall xbindkeys` did the work.